# Testcafe process fails to end when using reporters

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have observed that whenever I run my automated script along with reporter, the test runs through successfully but the testcafe process does not end. After closing the application browser the testcafe run window never closes. This happens only when run command includes reporter details like
'**testcafe chrome RegressionTestHappyFlows/calculatePremium_ShortTermTravelInsurance.ts --env=Test_English_ET --reporter html:TestRun.html**'.

If I remove the reporter details from the command then the testcafe process ends properly as expected. I have tried with testcafe-reporter-html(version : 1.4.6) and also with multiple-cucumber-html-reporter(version : 1.18.0). In both cases I face the same issue. Testcafe version that I am using is 1.9.1

Could some one please help and suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: I was not able to reproduce the issue using `testcafe-reporter-html`. I created a simple test with some click actions (https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/d46ec163f7180eefbcabc66422f3a7e1) and used the following command: `testcafe chrome test.js --reporter html:TestRun.html`. The test passed, and the process ended properly. Could you please share your test and project to demonstrate the issue? If you cannot share your full project, please prepare a reproducible sample.
Please also try installing the latest TestCafe version and check if the issue persists.

Comment: As for `multiple-cucumber-html-reporter`, it is not a TestCafe reporter. TestCafe reporter package names should contain the `testcafe-reporter` prefix.

Comment: Hi Alex...thanks for your reply... After trying again I find that the process closes fine and also the html report gets generated properly when the test is successfull ... If the test fails due to some reason the testcafe process does not close... Could you please try by making your sample test fail...

Comment: Hi, I tried to throw an error in the test. The test failed, and everything stopped as expected. Here is the test result: [https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/b3f5e8b64152eb19439fc5e0c0affceb](https://gist.github.com/AlexKamaev/b3f5e8b64152eb19439fc5e0c0affceb). Please modify my example to reproduce the issue.